# Why wp_editor is going outside the container?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have searched a lot about it but didn't find any answer.I am using wp_editor on frontend but its printed outside the div element.

below is a screenshot
[image]

And below is my codes

```
wp_editor( 
    $content = '', 
    $editor_id = 'ec_frontend_editor', 
    $settings =   array(
        'wpautop' => false, // use wpautop?
        'media_buttons' => true, // show insert/upload button(s)
        'textarea_name' => $editor_id, // set the textarea name to something different, square brackets [] can be used here
        'textarea_rows' => get_option('default_post_edit_rows', 10), // rows="..."
        'tabindex' => '',
        'editor_css' => '', //  extra styles for both visual and HTML editors buttons, 
        'editor_class' => '', // add extra class(es) to the editor textarea
        'teeny' => false, // output the minimal editor config used in Press This
        'dfw' => true, // replace the default fullscreen with DFW (supported on the front-end in WordPress 3.4)
        'tinymce' => true, // load TinyMCE, can be used to pass settings directly to TinyMCE using an array()
        'quicktags' => true // load Quicktags, can be used to pass settings directly to Quicktags using an array()
    )
)
```

Comment: I would check for HTML syntax errors.

Comment: @WhereDidMyBrainGo there is no HTML syntax error..

Answer (score 1):

it's been too late but it will be helpful for someone in future. I got same problem because of I am taking string:

```
$html = '';
$html .= wp_editor( $real_value, 'gg_contact_html_wp_editor', $wp_editor_settings );
echo $html;
```

then I replaced my code with this code:

```
<div class="container">
   wp_editor( $real_value, 'gg_contact_html_wp_editor', $wp_editor_settings );
</div>
```